# Python socket sending large amount of data

Tags: python, sockets

So I got just a simple question in python sockets. is the send function good enough for sending files?
does it care how much data I am sending to the server/client?

Comment: See the [how-to](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html) for limitations. Short version: always check the return value!

Comment: I tried the functions in there but I get an error saying that "MSGLEN" is not defined is there an import I need to make?

Comment: You shouldn't just copy/paste. You also have read the text.

Comment: okay fixed it now. I should really read more. anyway thank you so much for your help.